# Is there a tool to check in which browsers my website is displayed correctly?

Tags: web-development, web-browser, web, css

I'm creating a website with HTML and CSS and often you have to use special tags for an element to be displayed correctly and compatible in various browsers as in Edge like this:

```
-webkit-transition: 1s linear;
-moz-transition: 1s linear;
-ms-transition: 1s linear;
-o-transition: 1s linear;
transition: 1s linear;
```

I'm sure I've forgotten some of these at some point in my stylesheets and was wondering if there was a website, program, etc. that could tell me where I forgot these tags.

Do you know a tool something like this?